# How does my network "know" my internet connection speed?

Tags: networking

Let's say I have a 100mbit ethernet card, going to my 100mbit router, then to my cable modem; to which my ISP has sold me 50mbps.

Now let's say I start uploading an incredibly large file to a web server, and let's assume the web server can accept unlimited speeds (so we're focusing only on "my end").

What stops my upload from surpassing 50mbps?  Perhaps my cable modem is configured to only send that much data (over whatever type of link it has), but how does my (PC, to router, to cable modem) know to "thottle" it back?  How does my operating system know NOT to send data out my NIC at 100mbps because the connection downstream cannot handle it (my ISP/cable modem).

This is what I THINK I know:

If it's using TCP, it will use TCP's mechanisms to send accordingly.
If it's using UDP, it will spam away at 100mbps, eventually fill the buffer of my cable modem, and packets will be lost.  IF this is true, perhaps before this happens it will issue some other flow control message?

Can someone please explain!  I'm very curious!

Comment: "*If it's using UDP, it will spam away at 100mbps, eventually fill the buffer of my cable modem, and packets will be lost.*" What is the "it" here? It sounds like you are imagining some really poorly-written UDP program that blindly and stupidly saturates network links without any attempt at cooperation. Such a program might exist, but it would have to have been written by a fool and, hopefully, wouldn't be widely used by sane people. When you use UDP, *you* have to implement the stuff TCP does for you (except for stuff you know you don't need). Sane cooperation is needed in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

TCP provides upper layer end-to-end flow control to attempt to level our transmission speeds across every node it passes through so as not to hog any particular devices buffer, but [Layer 2 networks also provide direct flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control) messages, eg ETHERNETII PAUSE frames.

Your modem will tell your host to back off for a bit while the buffer spools out. The bigger issue is when a device in the middle of the network path has to buffer your UDP video stream. It can only quench the source one hop upstream, which presumably asks the same of its upstream comms partner. When the devices in the middle fill up though, they start dropping frames. UDP has always been Best-Effort, and this is a perfect example of it.

So, to sum up, your network doesn't actually know its connection speed, beyond computing transmission averages over time, but the hardware responds to the flow control mechanisms and heuristically arrives at a speed the network can cope with.

Comment: So my assumption is rather correct.  In the case the same connection is handling voice-over-IP and internet traffic, it's safe to say sending 100mbps of UDP traffic to the 50mbps-limited device will eventually spawn an ETHERNET PAUSE frame, thus potentially dropping phone calls, as well? (assuming no middle-man device flow control)

Comment: well, for flow control mechanisms, layer 2 is a bad place to do it (though completely necessary) as it loses value the further you get from the origin device. in your case, it would ask your PC to stop sending frames, since its 1 or fewer hops away, and the PAUSE frame can reach the sender directly. the idea is to avoid needing to drop frames. Additionally I would suspect that VOIP doesn't drop a call because a few frames are dropped. the digital signal is probably a digital reflection of a 48k analog sample, and can lose some data without issue.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, your cable modem is a layer 2 device so it is quite capable of sending PAUSE or Source Quench data units to the source. The source control messages are an attempt to avoid dropping packets, not part of the mechanism for doing so. The idea is to slow down the reception of data so that it can send out what it already has first. that can result in out-of-order reception, but most of the frames should eventually go through unless the source doesn't get or doesn't respond to receiving a pause frame.

Comment: @user334532 "*it's safe to say sending 100mbps of UDP traffic to the 50mbps-limited device will eventually spawn an ETHERNET PAUSE frame, thus potentially dropping phone calls, as well?*" If you continue sending more traffic than a link can handle, eventually some traffic will have to be dropped. But, again, you're imagining some horribly broken UDP application that makes no attempt at behaving sanely.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm thinking about this from a "network protection" standpoint; with no immediate need in mind, however.  I worry more about malicious intent these days than some program.